# Bigcommerce Webhook

Tags: php, bigcommerce, webhooks

I am trying to implement the Bigcommerce webhook and I have successfullly cretead the **store/product/updated*** webhook. When I am trying to get the response on my destination url, I am getting nothing. I am using following code to record the response which is send by webhook to my url. My code is

```
<?php 
$webhook_content = '';
$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while(!feof($webhook)){ //loop through the input stream while the end of file is not reached
    $webhook_content .= fread($webhook, 4096); //append the content on the current iteration
}
fclose($webhook); //close the resource
$data=$webhook_content;
$data = json_decode($webhook_content,true); //convert the json to array
$myfile = __DIR__.'/productupdatelog.txt';
file_put_contents($myfile, print_r($data,true));
?>
```

But still I am not getting anything. Bigcommerce team is saying that Checking out that destination URL we do appear to be sending you webhooks and properly receiving back a 200 response from your server. But I am not able too record anything.

Answer (score 1):

you can get it using file_get_content and store the response to file or database. you will get json encoded response within next 1 min.

```
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $webhookContent = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $result         = json_decode($webhookContent, true);            
  }
```

for more details : https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#respond-to-webhook-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

you can use file_get_contents and error_log to see the data:

```
$webhookContent = file_get_contents("php://input");
error_log($webhookContent);
```